# Why is there question activity indicated, but not actually present?

Tags: support

I have seen this several times already (also on other SE sites), but only captured it in a screenshot now.

The question shown below came up in the "active" question view. It shows that user Robert performed some activity on the question five hours ago.
[image]

However, when I go to [the question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33649/how-does-yongnuo-rf-603c-compare-with-cactus-v5-wireless-trigger) I don't see anyone named Robert that left a comment (or performed another activity) recently.

So what does this mean? Is it a bug? Is it a feature I don't understand?

p.s. I am sorry I picked a question of myself, it's not to boost views, just a coincidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case it's fairly simple: I deleted the response as it wasn't an answer. That happens a fair bit, usually from people who find the question using Google and responding without realizing that this isn't a discussion forum.  At sufficient rep, you'll be able to see the deleted info.